# Is there any case in python when using a while loop would be best practice?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, repeat, python-itertools

I'm doing some python benchmarking, and I've discovered that `repeat(None)` is much faster than `while True` or `while 1`:

```
>>> def bench7():
...   foo = 0
...   a = time()
...   for i in repeat(None):
...     foo += 1
...     if foo == 100000000:
...       break
...   b = time()
...   print a, b, b-a
... 
>>> def bench8():
...   foo = 0
...   a = time()
...   while True:
...     foo += 1
...     if foo == 100000000:
...       break
...   b = time()
...   print a, b, b-a
... 
>>> bench7()
1326592924.41 1326592935.42 11.0051281452
>>> bench7()
1326592936.36 1326592947.48 11.1183578968
>>> bench8()
1326592951.47 1326592965.03 13.5640599728
>>> bench8()
1326592966.07 1326592979.6 13.5341670513`
```

This sort of usage for a while loop was the last thing that I actually used while loops for.  Is there any reason left to use whiles that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `while True` is only slower because of the global lookup for `True`.  If you use `while 1` instead, the while-loop should handily beat the for-repeat (at least in terms of speed, beauty, and clarity):

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> def f():
        while True:
            print

>>> dis(f)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              11 (to 14)
        >>    3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       13
  3           9 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             10 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   13 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             17 RETURN_VALUE        

>>> def g():
        while 1:
            print

>>> dis(g)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP               4 (to 7)
  3     >>    3 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              4 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>    7 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

The main use case for *repeat* is to supply a stream of constant values to *imap* or *izip*.  For example, the following computes the sum of powers-of-two:  `sum(imap(pow, repeat(2), xrange(10)))`.

The *repeat* itertool can also be used  to speed-up a for-loop that doesn't need a changing variable.  For example, Guido used this technique to minimize looping overhead in the *timeit* module: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/40e1be1e0707/Lib/timeit.py#l188

To answer your other question, "are there any reasons to use a while-loop".  The answer is yes.  Python's for-loop is really a foreach that consumes  iterators to produce a stream of values.  In contrast, a while-loop is either unbounded (as in the while-True example) or terminated when a specific condition is met (for example, looping over user inputs until the user types "quit" or somesuch).

The contrasting capabilities of while-loops and for-loops can be seen in the example of the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) where the while-loop cannot be easily replaced with a for-loop:

```
def collatz(n):
    print n
    while n > 1:
        n = n // 2 if n % 2 == 0 else n * 3 + 1
        print n
```

Many more examples and use cases for while-loops can be seen by grepping over [Python's standard library](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/40e1be1e0707/Lib).

In summary, the while-statement is an essential part of your toolkit :-)

Comment: Today I learned about disassembling python functions, it's a same that I only have an upvote and accept to give.

Answer (score 1):

While loops allow for truth-value testing.

```
while x < y:
```

Is it possible that's why it is slower than repeat?

Comment: That does seem to be about 3% faster!

Comment: That isn't the cause.  A ``while 1`` gets optimized to a simple *JUMP_ABSOLUTE*.  The cause of the slowness is the time to lookup the global variable ``True``.

Answer (score 0):

`repeat(None)` is faster than `while True` but not `while 1` because `while True` triggers lookup for GLOBAL variable `True`.
`while 1` is about 14% faster than `repeat(None)`.

Comment: Well platform (OS,hardware,running process, etc.) varies. Result are according to my own test using above method, mentioned in Question.

Comment: You haven't specified your method at all. Your platform is relevant to understanding the meaning of the results.

Comment: Well as I mentioned before, the questions above have a script which  gives output in value of time, of different method used, so you can compare them according to there output. Also why down vote? If I am wrong then correct me.